# printf somehow works without passing in variable for the format string C

Tags: c

So I'm currently learning C and had to write a program that took in a character and checked if it was a vowel or consonant. While doing this I compiled but forgot the pass the char into printf and yet it still somehow worked and even displayed the char. Any clue how this could have happened or why?

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <ctype.h>

int main() {
    char chr;
    int ascii;

    printf("Enter a character: ");
    scanf(" %c", &chr);

    ascii = (int) toupper(chr);

    if (ascii == 65 || ascii == 69 || ascii == 73 || ascii == 79 || ascii == 85) {
        printf("%c is a VOWEL.\n");
    } else if (ascii >= 65 && ascii <= 90) {
        printf("%c is a CONSONANT.\n");
    } else {
        printf("%c is not a letter.\n");
    }

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: it simply read from some random address.

Comment: If you're using GCC, learn to use `-Wall -Werrror` now and save yourself hours of frustration.

Comment: The code exposes _undefined behavior_, thus isn't generally reproducible. Voted to close as _off-topic_.

Comment: The behaviour of `printf` is simply undefined for your case. You cannot rely on it.

Comment: This is a little like asking, "Yesterday I was driving down the road.  I accidentally fell asleep for one minute.  But the car kept going straight, didn't crash into anything.  How could this happen?"  And the answer, in both cases, is: you got lucky.  Obviously you can't depend on this.  For details on how you happened to get the right answer printed in your program, instead of some crazy, meaningless result, see Eric Postpischil's answer.

Comment: @πάνταῥεῖ The OP saw a strange result that he didn't understand.  The answer will improve his understanding of computers and programming.  Moreover, the strange result and the misunderstanding are not rare or isolated: this kind of question comes up for beginners *all the time*.  So vote to close it as a duplicate if you like, but I really don't think it's off-topic.

Comment: @BradenCoates Side note: It's much easier (and more readable and portable to boot) to write `if(ascii == 'A' || ascii == 'E' || ascii == 'I' || ascii == 'O' || ascii == 'U')`

Comment: Upvoted for describing the desired and observed behavior and providing a reasonably minimal, complete  example. More than most first-time posters accomplish.

Comment: @SteveSummit And then don't name the variable `ascii` ;-).

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Russian_roulette

Answer (score 4, accepted):

When a function is called, arguments are passed to it. These arguments are passed according to some specification that says where they are passed, commonly in processor registers or on the stack.

In the simplest implementation, the called function takes the values for its parameters from the locations where you are supposed to pass arguments. When you do not put a desired value in the right place, the function uses whatever value is there. If the program happened to use the same register for some variable, say `ascii`, that would be used for passing the argument, then it is possible that `printf` happens to get the desired value and print it.

However, that is just the simplest behavior. Modern compilers optimize programs considerably and may transform function calls into code that would be equivalent if your program had defined behavior. When you have undefined behavior, this optimization can result in your program misbehaving in surprising ways. It may print incorrect values, terminate with an error, or execute code other than what you expected.

To avoid some of these problems, compile with most warnings enabled (`-Wall` in GCC and at least `-Wmost` in Clang) and elevated to error messages (`-Werror` with GCC and Clang).